# Power Automate Flow Generating Proxy Error

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, blueprism

We have Blueprism (RPA) calling a Power Automate Flow to auto assign an item on Sharepoint. About 5% of these items fail in Blueprism with the following error. ERROR: Internal : Unexpected error The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

This flow is being called by multiple resources (potentially at the same time).

Comment: the 407 is an http error and coming from Sharepoint because the request from your PA Flow isn't providing the necessary credentials for it to succeed.  As this is only happening in a few cases where multiple resources are involved, the correct approach is to isolate the resources which are seeing the error and verify they are configured correctly with the appropriate permissions for the request to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was linked to a proxy setting on one of the resources. Replicated settings from other resources and flow is running correctly now.